Delete custom surround pairs
I have added:
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
                                  (push '(?' . ("‘" . "’")) evil-surround-pairs-alist)))

to my init files to add smart quotes (they are not showing properly here) instead of normal quotes while surrounding.
It works fine. Except that I can not delete these with ds'.
Is there a way to get ds also work?
